# Can't reinstall XAMPP after removal

Tags: xampp, uninstallation

I've got a problem since a couple of weeks that I can't rid of. 
I have installed XAMPP on my desktop (running Win 8.1), then I have uninstalled it to install a newer version (I couldn't simply upgrade at the time).
The process failed cause there were some file that the uninstall process wasn't able to remove (in c:/XAMPP directory). I've removed them manually without problems.

However, when I tried to reinstall the latest version, the installer simply **DIDN'T RUN**. I noticed that, after downloading it from the official site and launching it, the installer seems to work but after few secs my browser crashes. Then it stops working, I can't even restart it or kill the process definitely (I'm using Chrome but I tried also Firefox).

My questions are:

1. Why the installer doesn't work and I can't reinstall XAMPP ?
2. Why the installer makes my browsers crash ?

I can provide machine specs if needed !

Thank you !

Comment: Try to uninstall it with Revo Uninstaller, remove all files and registries related, reboot, then try to reinstall.

Comment: Thank you Bernardo,unfortunately I can't find any instance of XAMPP in the pc or in Revo...

Comment: No, I can't find anything...

Comment: Sorry for bumping...Anyone can help ?

Comment: I'm sorry, you have to point Revo Uninstaller forced uninstall to xampp folder, then select advanced, then delete all registries and files that Revo finds, then reboot and then try to install it again.

Comment: Hi bernardo, as I said before, I can't find the XAMPP folder anywhere

Comment: Try to install it on safe mode.